# Play Sound Effect Xcode 5

Tags: cocoa-touch

I want to do that every time I click on the picture it will make sound.
add at "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" 
AudioToolbox
and at GameViewController.h
add:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
{
SystemSoundID PlaySoundID;
}
- (IBAction)PlayAudioButton:(id)sender;
```

(connected this with button).

at GameViewController.m
add this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Sound"    ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);
}

- (IBAction)PlayAudioButton:(id)sender {

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);

}
```

after all isn't working no error but sound not woking...
what the problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                          pathForResource:@"yourSound"
                                          ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfURL:url
                    error:nil];

[sound play];
```

Comment: thanks but not working.. 

 
"use of undeclared identifier AVAudioPlayer"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but this is how I'd get the custom sound to play when you tap the button

make sure to

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in your .h or .m file

create an AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer property for your class (either in .h or .m) and then do this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad]
    NSError *error;
    NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    [theAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.audioPlayer = theAudioPlayer;
}

- (IBAction)PlayAudioButton:(id)sender{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```